# Flutter application not running in iPhone after upgrading iOS to 13.3.1

Tags: ios, flutter

Everything was fine. It was running in simulator as well as physical device in iphone. After upgrading my phone software version to 13.3.1 it stopped working. However, it is running in simulator. I get following error when trying to run from android studio.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on John’s iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: MFL3YAAR46
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           10.6s
Installing and launching...
Could not install build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 003308020-000D741G0A7A002E.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on John’s iPhone.
```

Then, I open flutter iOS in xcode and try to run from there and got following message with **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Flutter.framework/Flutter
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2E2CB44-5BE3-4200-A27A-7A7502859B1C/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's related to iOS 13.3.1 version and nothing to do with Flutter SDK. 
Please read https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504

It is fixed on iOS13.4 beta version. 
Till then, avoid using personal teams for Automatic Code signing.

Comment: You have to upgrade flutter to the last stable version!

Answer (score 0):

Same. Happens with any pod.
With everything I've done, I believe the fix it's on Apple's.

I've documented everything I've done here :
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/128435